# How to permanently delete file so that it becomes unrecoverable?

Tags: .net, winapi, file-io, operating-system, filesystems

If I want my application (written in .NET) to delete a file such that it can not be recovered by disk recovery tool. What are my options?

One that I can think of is that I open it up in write mode, overwrite all of it with some random data and it would make the file unrecoverable. Is there any other way?

Comment: I've looked at a couple different approaches, your proposed solution is what most people fall back on.   The others grow complicated very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Shell out to SDELETE:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx

you can specify the number of passes.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't overwriting the file with nothing do exactly as you want?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad english, i from Brazil.

This code is useful for C# applications (you can suit this code using VB Diagnostics class if you application is writted in VB, this not is so hard, the logic is same and simple).
Her use MS-DOS for delete the file, when a file has been deleted using the `DEL` command, we don't cant recovery ther.

Microsoft says:

> "If you use del to delete a file from your disk, you cannot retrieve it."

```
public void deleteFilePermanent(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileInfo.FullName))
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startCmd = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");

            // This arguments equals a: del -f C:\Exemple\Folder\file.name
            startCmd.Arguments = "/C del -f " + fileInfo.FullName;
            startCmd.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startCmd.UseShellExecute = false;

            using (Process cmdProc = new Process())
            {
                cmdProc.StartInfo = startCmd;
                cmdProc.Start();
                cmdProc.WaitForExit();
                cmdProc.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```